# Websphere v8.5.5 + JAX-WS generate nil tag

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, websphere-8

I have an application with EJB 3.1, Hibernate 3.3.1-GA and serveral webservices in JAX-WS running in WAS v8.5.

After upgrade Hiberante to 4.2.18, and change classloader from PARENT_FIRST to PARNT_LAST, all webservices have stopped working. The XML generate from my server have new tag, and i don't know why. Like this,

```
<nil>false</nil>
<value xsi:type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2015-06-08T00:00:00.116+02:00</value>
```

Request before upgrade

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns2:CancelOT xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/">
        <woCancel>
            <cancelRequestDateTime>2015-06-08T00:00:00.116+02:00</cancelRequestDateTime>
            <cancellationMotive>Eliminaci&#243;n de orden</cancellationMotive>
            <operationalSiteID>0713</operationalSiteID>
            <otClassID>1</otClassID>
            <otGotID>1746039</otGotID>
            <otOriginID>O7760325</otOriginID>
        </woCancel>
    </ns2:CancelOT>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Request after upgrade

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns2:CancelOT xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/">
        <woCancel>
            <cancelRequestDateTime>
                <nil>false</nil>
                <value xsi:type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2015-06-08T00:00:00.116+02:00</value>
            </cancelRequestDateTime>
            <cancellationMotive>Eliminaci&#243;n de orden</cancellationMotive>
            <operationalSiteID>0713</operationalSiteID>
            <otClassID>
                <nil>false</nil>
                <value xsi:type="xs:int" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">1</value>
            </otClassID>
            <otGotID>1746039</otGotID>
            <otOriginID>O7760325</otOriginID>
        </woCancel>
    </ns2:CancelOT>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Anyone have a idea?

Comment: Can you share the logs?

Comment: I don't think Hibernate change would cause this behaviour unless there's now a null reference in the object. The main reason is probably the change of  classloader policy from PARENT_FIRST to PARNT_LAST as this would cause that WebSphere instead of using it's own libraries uses the one packaged with your application. What libraries do you have packaged with your application? 
BTW - as far as I know the default behaviour of most parsers is to have the property field:nil="false" and in that case doesn't show any null references.

Comment: @Prerak, What do you watch on the logs? the problem is when other system call me by webservice they cann't regonize new tags, because is not valid.

Comment: @Marcos, i think that is it, the change of classloader. But i have tried to change diference library (even version of them), axis2, jaxws,...

Ear libs
[IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/4giwyo.jpg[/IMG]
[IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/9qwd8g.jpg[/IMG]

War libs
[IMG]http://i57.tinypic.com/2n1do3t.jpg[/IMG]
[IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/mtt5cg.jpg[/IMG]
[IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/334iwb6.jpg[/IMG]
[IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/1z3sdhu.jpg[/IMG]
Thanks to help me

Comment: i found the problem!! another of my projects had dependency of jaxb-api-2.2.5.jar. This library caused the error. thanks a lot guys!